# React Native usage and architecture at facebook, Meta

Tags: react-native, facebook, mobile-application

I am a student working on my thesis researching cross-platform app development with React Native. I'm hoping someone can provide some insight into how Meta utilize React Native within their mobile app engineering organization.

Specifically:

- Does Meta still maintain dedicated iOS and Android engineering teams
  in addition to their central React Native cross-platform team? Or has
- the organization shifted more resources directly into React Native as the main mobile development focus?
- Beyond the open-source React Native framework, does Meta leverage any proprietary or in-house cross-platform libraries/tools?
- Are certain performance-critical parts of the app still native, while other components like the marketplace section may be React Native?

Getting perspective from Meta engineers directly would provide valuable real-world context for my research. Any information you can share on your React Native adoption strategy and how you architect your apps would be greatly appreciated.

Please feel free to omit any proprietary details you cannot disclose publicly. I am most interested in the high-level organization structure and decision-making around React Native.

Thank you for taking the time to read this! Any insights you can offer would help strengthen my thesis research.